# What does this mean in objective-c: @interface SomeClass() <SomeOtherClass>

Tags: objective-c

I am starting off in the iOS development world and encountered something unfamiliar. In my `MainViewController.m` file, I have:

```
//import statements

@interface MainViewController() <CarouselViewDelegate>
//declaration of properties
@end

@implementation
//code
@end
```

The `MainViewController.h` file looks like this

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
//code
@end
```

What I'm confused about is, what does this do (in a general sense): `@interface MainViewController() <CarouselViewDelegate>`. It looks like its using generics but not exactly sure what is happening here.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Objective-C has no generics. It's a protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first part `@interface MainViewController()` is a [class extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

and it allows you to extend the class interface in a private way (not in the header file). It is the same thing as an Objective-C [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html), but is anonymous.

the second bit `<CarouselViewDelegate>` says that the class extension will conform to the `CarouselViewDelegate` [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

All a protocol is is an interface that defines methods that a class can (`@optional`) or must (`@required`) adopt to work in some capacity for another class. In this case the protocol is a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) protocol for some class called `CarouselView`.

You would have to look at the specific protocols documentation or interface to see what it does. You also have to connect at least one instance of `CarouselView` to the `MainViewController` delegate in order for it to be useful; typically this is done in interface builder using [IBOutlets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html), but can be done programmatically such as `cv.delegate = mainVC`.

Comment: Most complete answer here

Answer (score 0):

That means that you are going to implement the delegate called `CarouselViewDelegate`

In other words, `CarouselViewDelegate` is a set of methods published by another class (probably called `CarouselView`) that is expecting somebody to implement. In this case, your `MainViewController` will implement them.

Kind of an interface in Java, but not the same.

More info here:

[Delegates and Datasources in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)

Comment: Thanks for quick response, it makes more sense now. I hadn't known what it was called so I was unsure as to what I should search for.